# How to get current location from Google+ API for Android?

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

I need to get current location from Google+ API for Android.

I have done everything in Google API Console, and linked my app with client ID with SHA1 and package name.

I successfully get almost data about user name, profile picture, cover picture, email...

But I have problem with location. I can't get user location.

I use this scope:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null)
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE).build();
```

I use this code to get profile information:

```
 String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String userId = currentPerson.getId();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
            String location = currentPerson.getCurrentLocation();
            String coverPhoto = currentPerson.getCover().getCoverPhoto().getUrl();
```

And I sucessfully get all this data, but I get null as location.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you add the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to your manifest?

Comment: Nope, I didn't. I will try right know.

Comment: I added those permissions, but it's null again.

Comment: @Zookey: Was this issue solved? Are you getting the cover photo URL for users who have not set cover photo? I have a strange issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995808/google-plus-cover-photo-in-android

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `currentLocation` values are not [currently available through the API](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=620).

Comment: Hm, my colleague gets currentLocation for his iPhone app. Is this issue is only Android related?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, based on the issue there might be undocumented scopes that enable it. Maybe your colleague has extra scopes in use?

Comment: He uses PROFILE scope and I also use it as you can see it from the code above.