# How can I get my friends location using Google Plus API?

Tags: android, geolocation, google-plus

I have some difficult task. I need to take locations of my friends from google+ on map. I already sign my google+ account on my application and load names of friends. There is code:

```
private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GoogleApiClient mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context, this, this)
                                        .addApi(Plus.API)
                                        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                                        .build();
    mApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(connector.getApiClient())+" is connected", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Person person = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(connector.getApiClient());
    Log.d("Position of person", person.getCurrentLocation().toString());
}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    mConnectionResult = result;
    FixErrors();
}
```

Toast is called with " is connected", I have my name in `person.getDisplayName()` but location is `NULL`. I already created OAurh key in Google Developer Console. Maybe I need to request some rights of authorised user? If yes, please tell me how can I do it. If no, how can I take a position of my friends?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the API is not just working right for android, as is suggested in 2 months old question: [How to get current location from Google+ API for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408728/how-to-get-current-location-from-google-api-for-android)