# Google Plus Cover Photo in android

Tags: android, google-plus

I am trying to get Google plus cover photo using the following code:

```
if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) 
{
  Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
  String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
  String userId = currentPerson.getId();
  personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
  String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();

  boolean coverphoto = currentPerson.getCover().hasCoverPhoto();

  String urlBackgroud = currentPerson.getCover().getCoverPhoto().getUrl();

  String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
   Log.e("url","Background"+photo);
   Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl + ", userId: " + userId );
```

When I have set the Cover photo. I get the result with URL but I don't set the cover photo then I get the following error

```
  07-28 18:18:39.952: W/System.err(9566): java.lang.NullPointerException
  07-28 18:18:39.952: W/System.err(9566):   at com.ylg.maps.MainActivity.getProfileInformation(MainActivity.java:224)
  07-28 18:18:39.952: W/System.err(9566):   at com.ylg.maps.MainActivity.onConnected(MainActivity.java:178)
  07-28 18:18:39.952: W/System.err(9566):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.hd.c(Unknown Source)
  07-28 18:18:39.952: W/System.err(9566):   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.eF(Unknown Source)
  07-28 18:18:39.952: W/System.err(9566):   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.d(Unknown Source)
  07-28 18:18:39.952: W/System.err(9566):   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c$2.onConnected(Unknown Source)
  07-28 18:18:39.952: W/System.err(9566):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.hd.c(Unknown Source)
  07-28 18:18:39.952: W/System.err(9566):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.hd.ck(Unknown Source)
  07-28 18:18:39.952: W/System.err(9566):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.hc$h.b(Unknown Source)
  07-28 18:18:39.952: W/System.err(9566):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.hc$h.d(Unknown Source)
  07-28 18:18:39.959: W/System.err(9566):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.hc$b.fq(Unknown Source)
  07-28 18:18:39.959: W/System.err(9566):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.hc$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
  07-28 18:18:39.959: W/System.err(9566):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  07-28 18:18:39.959: W/System.err(9566):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  07-28 18:18:39.959: W/System.err(9566):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
  07-28 18:18:39.959: W/System.err(9566):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  07-28 18:18:39.959: W/System.err(9566):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  07-28 18:18:39.959: W/System.err(9566):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
  07-28 18:18:39.959: W/System.err(9566):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
  07-28 18:18:39.959: W/System.err(9566):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Then I tried:

```
boolean coverphoto = currentPerson.getCover().hasCoverPhoto();
```

I am still getting the above error. How to solve the issue for user's not settings cover photo?

Thanks!

Comment: is `currentPerson.getCover().hasCoverPhoto();` returns false when no cover pic have set ?

Comment: @Spring Breaker : It is giving the same NullPointerException

Comment: have you initialized `currentPerson`  like this `Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);` ?

Comment: Can you post line number 224 & 178?

Comment: Line#224: boolean photo = currentPerson.getCover().hasCoverPhoto();

Line#178: getInformation(); (This is the method - which has code to fetch profile details..)

Comment: @SpringBreaker : Does it work for you? even though your cover photo is default?

Comment: though I haven't tested it, I am sure it will work. `currentPerson.getCover().hasCoverPhoto();` will return either `true` or `false`, so if it shows `NPE` then `currentPerson` is null probably.See whether you are initializing it before getting the coverphoto line.

Comment: As I said the same code works fine when I try on a user's profile that has cover photo so I everything is perfect and strange it is not working. It would be great if you could test it out and let me know!

Comment: Well your code seems to be ok.I don't find any error on it.

Comment: For now, a workaround would be surround that snippet within try catch block and set `ImageView` background to some default image in the `catch` section.

Comment: Hmm.. I have implemented the workaround. It is working.. It would be great if you could try out without the try / catch and let me know! Thanks!

Comment: @TheDevMan : did u find a solution to this ?

Comment: @TerrilThomas: Nope. I am just using try and catch as a workaround..

Comment: check if currentPerson.hasCover() is true or false, if true then only currentPerson.getCover.getCoverPhoto().getUrl() will be returned correctly.

Comment: Also check if your Plus and People Api are enabled in developer console.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make an additional call when your google client is connected 
as follow :

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
Plus.PeopleApi.load(mGoogleApiClient, person.getId())
                            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult) {
                            if (loadPeopleResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                PersonBuffer personBuffer = loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer();
                                if (personBuffer != null && personBuffer.getCount() > 0) {
                                    Person currentUser = personBuffer.get(0);
                                    personBuffer.release();
                                    Person.Cover cover = currentUser.getCover();
                                    if (cover != null) {
                                        Person.Cover.CoverPhoto coverPhoto = cover.getCoverPhoto();
                                        if (coverPhoto != null) {
                                            String userCoverPhotoUrl = coverPhoto.getUrl();
                                            Log.i("Main TAG", "Cover photo Url :" + userCoverPhotoUrl);

                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        Log.i("TAG NO COVER", "Person has no cover");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

}
```