# Getting cover photo url with the new Google Sign-In for Android

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

I'm trying to implement new Google sign-in (`com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0`) to my app. I'm following the tutorial here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating. I need to get cover photo url and couldn't find any documentation about how to get it using the classes like `GoogleSignInResult` or `GoogleSignInAccount`.

In the old version, I was using `Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson().getCover().getCoverPhoto().getUrl()` method to get cover photo but it looks like in the new version they removed `Plus` class completely.

Comment: I think you can try an answer at the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995808/google-plus-cover-photo-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You can get the person Google+ profile data using the new sign in API. Use Person - Google APIs for Android in [getting cover photo url](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.Cover.CoverPhoto.html#getUrl()).

Sample code snippet below:

```
Person.Cover.CoverPhoto cover = person.getCover().getCoverPhoto();
String coverUrl = cover.getUrl();
```

Here's a sample Demo app for Google Sign in:
https://github.com/ngocchung/googlesignindemo

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it looks like they removed `com.google.android.gms.plus` package which includes `Person.Cover.CoverPhoto` on the last version :(

Comment: In `https://github.com/ngocchung/GoogleSignInDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/googlesignindemo/MainActivity.java` you will find that I use `Uri uri = acct.getPhotoUrl();` in `private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) ` :)

Comment: And pls pay attention to the comments `// FOR PROFILE PICTURE:
        // Ref: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount.html#getPhotoUrl%28%29
        // getPhotoUrl(): Gets the photo url of the signed in user.
        // Only non-null if requestProfile() is configured and user does have a Google+ profile picture.`. Hope it helps!

Comment: @BNK thank you but these are for profile photo, I need to get the cover photo.

Comment: @iamkaan: I have used `if (person.getCover() != null){
                        Log.i(TAG, "Cover Photo: " + person.getCover().getCoverPhoto().getUrl());
                    }` and the result is `03-14 08:16:24.227 3587-3587/com.example.googlesignindemo I/GoogleSignIn: Cover Photo: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/TwHrwftk8BaWEV4swcWDtdcg1halIcT2U3EWkXYkDyYPXmufMLtn1DJG569HIIsd4ty4=s630-fcrop64=1,2202423de15ce329` :)